# What's the best way to thank good commentators?

Tags: discussion, comment

Sometimes we are working on particular problem and we feel that we are close to the solution but somehow we can't break through this thin edge which separates us from the goal. So we ask question on **MSE**. And it happens that some commentator gives us not detailed solution but no more that a hint which makes however passage to the solution possible and shortens us a great deal of work and trials.
How can we express our gratitude to this good commentator?
It is appropriate to leave in comments some more personal remarks?

Comment: I'd guess that one possibility is upvoting a useful comment. (This might also be useful for other readers of the same post, since if a comment is upvoted, they are more likely to notice it.)

Comment: @Martin Up-voted comments are always sorted to the top?

Comment: @Widawenses You can learn more about how comments are displayed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271233/what-is-the-order-of-comments-for-each-post-in-all-stackexchange-communities).

Comment: @Martin I'm interested also whether comments have influence on this list of newest or active ones. Probably not but i haven't found this information. I hope that users have more freedom in creating and deleting comments than in questions and answers.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "active ones", but I guess that you could mean active questions. Comments do not bump question, as you can read [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/bumping/info). (There is also link to some further details about bumping.)

Comment: @ Yes, it is all about this bumping process and what has influence on it..

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You should tell them to convert their comments into an answer (preferably a full answer). Then you can upvote that answer, accept it... Comments are not meant for hints or answers; they're meant for asking clarification or adding information. A question that only receives answers in the comments will stay in the unanswered list, people will have to sift through many comments to find the actual answer, comments can easily and irremediably be deleted, they will be hidden by default if there are many comments and they don't get upvoted much, etc.

If they don't, and you managed to solve the problem yourself, feel free to post an answer yourself using their comment as a basis – you can thank them in the answer. If you want other people to edit that answer more easily, you can post it as "community wiki" (which has the *side* effect that you won't gain any reputation from it).

Comment: Answer is in even broader sense that I expected. I'm still learning rules of MSE.

Comment: I'm glad you said that. When I have an utterly trivial and very short answer I've tended to post it as a comment, feeling that posting something so insignificant as an answer would  make me a rep whore. But you point out good reasons why even trivial answers are better given as answers.  Huh.

Comment: But I experienced that posting a "simple" (trivial ?) answer, was "automatically" (by someone ?) CONVERTED to comment

Comment: @GCab The conversion is automatic. Your answer has to be *very* short for this to happen, and contain a link to another question. Include a bit more details and you should be good.

Comment: This is always what I do. "Hey, that solved it for me. If you make it an answer I'll upvote and accept it so you can get the rep. :)"